# How to save the path of a file obtained from the user in a Json file?

Tags: python, json, kivy, kivymd

I want to save the path of a image file obtained from user in a JSON file and change the image according to the path. The path is saved in the JSON file like this,

`{"PathInfo": {"cover_path": "\"E:\\K75 Programming\\Python\\Mode\\Photos\\2.jpg\""}}`

Therefore the image will not be changed. I want to save the path like this,

- `{"PathInfo": {"cover_path": "E:\K75 Programming\Python\Mode\Photos\2.jpg"}}`

I think then the picture will be changed properly. So, how would I do that?

Here is my code

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

screen_helper = """

ScreenManager:
    Studio:
    EditCover:
    
<Studio>:
    name : 'studio'
    MDFloatLayout:
        FitImage:
            id: cover_pic
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 1, .75
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1}
            source: "Photos/3.jpg"
    
<EditCover>:
    name : 'edit_cover'
    MDTextField:
        id : cover_path
        hint_text: "Path"
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        size_hint: (0.68,0.07)
    MDRaisedButton:
        text : 'OK'
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.08}
        font_style: 'Button'
        ripple_rad_default : 40
        ripple_duration_out : 1
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
        on_press : app.save_pic_path()
        
"""


class EditCover(Screen):
    pass


class Studio(Screen):
    pass


class Mode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def save_pic_path(self):
        self.cover_path = self.root.get_screen('edit_cover').ids.cover_path.text
        self.store_paths.put('PathInfo', cover_path = self.cover_path)
        self.pic_changer()

    def pic_changer(self):
        self.root.get_screen('studio').ids.cover_pic.source = "{self.store_paths.get('PathInfo')['cover_path']}"

    def on_start(self):
        self.store_paths = JsonStore("paths.json")

        try:
            if self.store_paths.get('PathInfo')['cover_path'] != "":
                self.pic_changer()

        except KeyError as e:
            self.root.get_screen('studio').ids.cover_pic.source = "Photos/3.jpg"

Mode().run()
```

However, I just want to get the path from user and change the image according to it.

- Can this be done correctly from the way I thought?
- Or, is there any better way to do this properly?

Please kindly help me to complete this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign the cover_path value to pic source, I think you forgot to use the f-string notation as the following code:

```
def pic_changer(self):
    self.root.get_screen('studio').ids.cover_pic.source = f"{self.store_paths.get('PathInfo')['cover_path']}"
```

I hope can help you

Comment: Oh! I have forgotten that. And I was failed to find the issue. @kuroaza sir Thanks a lot.